# UITableView SIGBRT error when trying to "swipe left to delete " at indexpath.row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, struct

I have a simple app that populates a UITableView based on data inputed in a different ViewController. I am trying to implement the "swipe left to delete" 
My problem is that this UITableView is a dropdown table view. That is when I click on one cell of the UITableView the cells open up and show me the internal cells associated with that one cells.

I think I am missing something simple as my code to delete the row does not work, it just throws a SIGBRT error. I think because maybe I trying to remove the wrong array maybe? I think it is messed up because it is a dropdown UITableView, so I am left with a bunch of extra UITableview rows?

Code to added delete button and remove selected row.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {

        // remove the item from the data model
        tableViewData.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        // delete the table view row
       tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

Whole code in the UITableViewController is as follows:

```
   import Foundation
   import UIKit

   private let reuseidentifier = "Cell"

   struct cellData {
       var opened = Bool()
       var title = String()
       var exerciseData = [String]()
       var repsSetsData = [String]()
   }

   //here
   struct Contact {
       var fullname: String
       var exercises : [Exercise]

   }

   class Exercise : NSObject , NSSecureCoding{

static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true

var excerciseName: String
var excerciseReps: String
var excerciseSets: String

init(Name : String, Reps : String, Sets : String) {
     excerciseName = Name
     excerciseReps = Reps
     excerciseSets = Sets
 }

 func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
     aCoder.encode(excerciseName, forKey: "excerciseName")
     aCoder.encode(excerciseReps, forKey: "excerciseReps")
     aCoder.encode(excerciseSets, forKey: "excerciseSets")
 }


 required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
     let excerciseName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "excerciseName") as! String
     let excerciseReps = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "excerciseReps") as! String
     let excerciseSets = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "excerciseSets") as! String

    self.init(Name: excerciseName, Reps: excerciseReps, Sets: excerciseSets)

        }
   }

   class ContactController: UITableViewController {

       //new
       var tableViewData = [cellData]()
       var contacts = [Contact]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //getting data from CoreData
    self.contacts = CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.retrieveDataFromCoreData()
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ExerciseCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ExerciseCell")

    for contact in contacts{

        var exerciseData = [String]()
        var repsSetsData = [String]()
        for exercise in contact.exercises{
        let name = exercise.excerciseName
        let sets = exercise.excerciseSets
        let reps = exercise.excerciseReps

        exerciseData.append(name)
        repsSetsData.append("Reps: " + reps + "      Sets: " + sets)

        }

            self.tableViewData.append(cellData.init(opened: false, title: contact.fullname, exerciseData:exerciseData, repsSetsData: repsSetsData))


    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.navigationItem.title = "Workouts"

    view.backgroundColor = .white
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseidentifier)

}


@IBAction func handleAddContact(_ sender: Any) {
    let controller = AddContactController()
    controller.delegate = self

    self.present(UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller), animated: true, completion: nil)

       }

       //UITABLEVIEW
       //all new
       override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
           //new
           return tableViewData.count
       }

       override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    //new
    if tableViewData[section].opened == true {
        return tableViewData[section].exerciseData.count + 1
    }else {
        return 1
           }
       }


       override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseidentifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].title
        return cell
    }else {
        //use a different cell identifier if needed
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExerciseCell", for: indexPath) as! ExerciseCell
        cell.exerciseLabel.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].exerciseData[indexPath.row - 1]
        cell.repsSetsLabel.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].repsSetsData[indexPath.row - 1]
        cell.repsSetsLabel.sizeToFit()

        return cell
           }
       }



       //did select row new
       override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened == true {
        tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = false
        let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
        tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none) //play around with animation
    }else {
        tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = true
        let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
        tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none) //play around with animation
           }
       }



       //being able to delete a row
       // this method handles row deletion
       override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {

        // remove the item from the data model
        tableViewData.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        // delete the table view row
       tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
           }

       }
   }

   //this is an extention to addContactController. this is what happens whent he done button is clicked in addcontactcontroller

   extension ContactController: AddContactDelegate {
       func addContact(contact: Contact) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true) {

    //Saving Data to CoreData
    CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.addContactsToCoreData(contact: contact)
    self.contacts.append(contact)

    //Settings values in table view
    var exerciseData = [String]()
    var repsSetsData = [String]()

    for exercise in contact.exercises{
        let name = exercise.excerciseName
        let sets = exercise.excerciseSets
        let reps = exercise.excerciseReps

        exerciseData.append(name)
        repsSetsData.append("Reps: " + reps + "      Sets: " + sets)

    }

        self.tableViewData.append(cellData.init(opened: false, title: contact.fullname, exerciseData:exerciseData, repsSetsData: repsSetsData))

    self.tableView.reloadData()
       }
   }
   }
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the rows can you try to reload the tableview cells like this: self.tableView.reloadData()

Comment: I have tried this but it unfortunately doesn't work. i even tried combining this with @Sh_Khans solution but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed that you delete a row not an entire section , so replace

```
tableViewData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

with

```
tableViewData[indexPath.section].exerciseData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

also make sure `exerciseData` is mutable ( declared as var )

Comment: Do you think it is because I am using core data?